# Sort multiple rows in Excel to move empty columns to right

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with about 3000 rows and 2500 columns. Most of the columns are full of zeros (but they do need to be there, for other reasons). I would like to sort the sheet so that all the empty columns are away to the right. The sheet looks like this:

```
ID       val1       val2       val3 ..... val2499       val2500   
1         1         2           0            0             1   
2         2         6           0            0             5   
3         0         5           0            0             0  
4         0         3           0            0             0   
5         1         1           0            0             2
```

What I want is for all the columns which have at least one non-zero entry to be gathered on the left (in any order) and all the columns which are entirely zeros to be on the right, so the above example would look like this:

```
ID       val1       val2     val2500 ..... val3         val2499   
1         1         2           1            0             0   
2         2         6           5            0             0   
3         0         5           0            0             0  
4         0         3           0            0             0   
5         1         1           2            0             0
```

It would not matter if val3 and val2499 were the other way round. I have tried the following and it did not work:

```
for row=1 to 2500
    Range("A1:CAA2500").Sort Key1:=Range("B" & b), Order1:=xlDescending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
next row
```

I know the code above is stupid and iterating through each row will probably not work but I cant think how to do this in one go, or if it can be done at all.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way of doing this, but this is what I have for the moment.

- Code assumes data (to sort) is on sheet `"Sheet1"` but change as necessary.
- Uses a temporary row (immediately below your data) and works out how many non-zeros are in each column.
- Each column gets sorted by its non-zero count (computed in the previous step)
- Once sorted, the temporary row is cleared and the sorting process is considered complete.

Not great and it might be slow depending on the size of your data (e.g. formulas that affect thousands of cells). That said, it should work.

It may benefit you to toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Calculation` before and after the code. Also, if you have data immediately below the range you want to sort, maybe you can instead `Range.Insert` a new row to use as `temporaryRow`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CustomSort()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim rangeToSort As Range
        Set rangeToSort = .Range("A1:F6")

        Dim temporaryRow As Range
        Set temporaryRow = rangeToSort.Offset(rangeToSort.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1)
        temporaryRow.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & rangeToSort.Columns(1).Address(True, False, xlA1) & ",""<>0"")"

        Application.Union(rangeToSort, temporaryRow).Sort Key1:=temporaryRow, Order1:=xlDescending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

        temporaryRow.Clear

    End With

End Sub
```

As I said, maybe there is a better way. But I couldn't find anything in the documentation for `Range.Sort` or via the Macro Recorder. So this is just a workaround.